# Связь по openssh до windows машины. Как создавать authorized_keys

Tags: windows, ssh

Цель - установить связь от CentOS до WindowsServer. Настроил связь сперва по паролю

```
ssh "domain\user@10.77.52.8"
```

получилось, всё нормально. Теперь хочу  настроить связь по сертификату и  начались пляски. Во первых я не понимаю где должен храниться файл authorized_keys. Если он должен храниться в  %userprofile%.ssh, то почему я не могу создать директорию .ssh в windows (недопустимое имя).
Или, почему не отрабатывает команда:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh "domain\user@10.77.52.8" "mkdir -p ~/.ssh && cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

(ошибка The syntax of the command is incorrect. догадываюсь, что на стороне windows я запускаю линукс команду, что естеств неправильно). Почему нигде нет информации как запустить команду от линукс до windows?
Почему не работает утилита **ssh-copy-id "domain\user@10.77.52.8"**  ('exec' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. The system cannot find the path specified.) Причем, если я пробую админского user то Permission denied
Куча неурядиц.  Где создавать authorized_keys ? Как создавать authorized_keys ? Кто нибудь может дать развернутый ответ или команду ориентированную на конечную windows машину?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119494/discussion-on-question-by-oleg0341---openssh--windows---).

Answer (score 0):

Удалось решить. Основное:

- Публичный ключ надо размещать в профайле пользователя
  C:\Users\user.ssh\authorized_keys (Нигде не упомянается про профайл! лишь "~/.ssh/authorized_keys" - это так же понятно, как индусу -где находится
  лепешечная, если ты не индус -твои проблемы называется)
- Папку ".ssh" создавать из командной строки (чисто линуксовая тема) из
  проводника естеств нельзя.
- Ключ копируется просто текстовым редактором из id_rsa.pub в
  authorized_keys (команду в строчку из линукса отработать так и не
  удалось, пока времени нет).
- На 2019 сервере ssh устанавливается как компонент (про 2019 также
  мало упоминаний, везде качают openssh с сайта и оттуда ставят)
- В 2019 разрешения на ключи уже настраивать ненужно и лезть в папку
  sshd config ненужно на всех этапах настройки, если только явно что-то
  не отключать.

Отсутствие законченных инструкций про связку Linux-WindowsWerver2019 требуют таких вот усилий в настройке.